# Is there a way to find polygons by specifying distance to border in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I need to find a polygon that has a border within a certain distance from a point. I just learned that [`$geoNear`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) uses the distance to the center of a shape. So I do not know how far I am from the border.

Using [`$geoWithin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) with `$center` does not work because [`$geoWithin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) only returns objects that are completely within. Last but not least I can not use $center with [`$geoIntersects`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects) that would also be a possible solution.

So at the moment it seems the only thing I can do is to calculate a circle like polygon shape around my spot and ask mongo which polygon [`$geoIntersects`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects) with it.
Or is there a better way to do it?